# indexPathForSelectedRow always returns 0 for both selected section and row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am developing iOS App with `UITableViewCell`.
When a `UITableViewCell` is tapped and goes to another screen with `segue`, `indexPathForSelectedRow` always returns 0 for both selected section and row.

My code is following.

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
   return 2;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
     if(section == 0) {
         return 3;
     }
     else if(section == 1) {
         return 2;
     }
     return 0;
 }

 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     return 50.0;
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     NSString *cellIdentifer = @"editCell";

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifer forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell==nil){
         cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifer];
    }

    UITextView *editText = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
       if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        editText.text = @"aaa";
       } else if(indexPath.row == 1){
        editText.text = @"bbb";
       } else {
        editText.text = @"ccc";
       }
    }
    else if(indexPath.section == 1) {
       if(indexPath.row == 0) {
           editText.text = @"ddd";
       } else if(indexPath.row == 1){
           editText.text = @"eee";
       }
   }

   return cell;
 }

 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"editDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSLog(@"a%d",indexPath.section);
        NSLog(@"b%d",indexPath.row);
 }
```

Comment: As an aside, for some time now there is no longer a requirement to check `if(cell == nil)` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: See this link -- http://hsoienterprises.com/2012/02/05/uitableview-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-storyboard-and-voiceover-doesnt-work/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the method in your link. However, my problem is not solved. Cell is correctly displayed.

Comment: Your code looks ok, so I have a couple of questions... 1. Are the `NSLog` calls returning any lines in terminal?; 2. You are using a Storyboard, so have you checked that the segue identifier value is definitely entered as "editDetail"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, you're missing ;

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

perform a transition from this method and you'll have access to the indexPath directly

Comment: Thank you for your reply. By your method, I can get correct section value and row value in [- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath]. However I cannot get collect value in [- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender]. Could you tell me how to cast correct value to the next screen?

Comment: You can add identifiers to your segue, then call         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self]; from the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 0):

You probably deselected your row somewhere in your code. Most likely in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. It's a common practice to deselect a row that has just been selected. If you deselected the row, this will cause you to get 0 in the `prepareForSegue` method when you try to get the indexPath.row.